# Remove iOS 6 ScrollView Center Alignment

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to create a page control in iOS 6.
I am using the interface builder to create the scrollView and have stretched out the screen using freeform simulated metrics.

There are 5 different views in the scrollview and the problem arises with the center view. I would like to align this to the left view and not to the center of the superview.The problem is when I set it to be 0pt from the left view it automatically creates a constraint Align Center X to Superview.

Align Center X to Superview is causing an unable to satisfy constraints crash.

How can I fix/remove this?
[image: scrollview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select page 2 and page 3, and choose Editor > Pin > Horizontal Spacing. This creates a constraint between the right edge of page 2 and the left edge of page 3. Now you can select and delete the centering constraint.

Basically the rule is simply that you can't remove a constraint in Xcode unless other constraints exist that completely determine the position / size of everything. You create those constraints with the Pin menu.